# MongoDB $lookup to replace only the ID in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I have the following example JSON-object saved in my mongodb-collection named "Profile"

```
{
   name: "Test",
   relations: [
      { 
          personid: <MongoDB-ID>, 
          type: "Friend", 
          duration: 5 
      },
      { 
          personid: <MongoDB-ID>, 
          type: "Family", 
          duration: 9 
      },
   ]
}
```

I've used the mongoose-Aggregate function because i need to add artificial fields based on caluclation in the documents saved. At the end of my aggregation i use the $lookup-function to replace the property "personID" in the objects inside of the "relations"-array.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: PersonModel.collection.name,
       localField: 'relations.personid',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: "relations.personid"
     }
}
```

Because i want each "person" in the array of objects to replaced within the populated from the specific person-document.
This does not work as expected.
I also tried to call ".populate()" on the result returned by the aggregate function which also not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `localField` to `relations.personid` is not supported. `localField` either needs to [`point to an array`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#unwind-example) where each member is used for the join or be a plain value. The usual way of getting around this is to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first, perform the lookup, and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) back if needed.